# Vaadin catch "Could not navigate to 'route' and redirect to existing route

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin14

I am doing a Vaadin App that has three Views, and whenever the users enters an unknown URL he sees this page:

Could not navigate to 'stackoverflow'
Reason: Couldn't find route for 'stackoverflow'

Available routes:
app
login
logout

This detailed message is only shown when running in development mode.
I want to define a route instead of showing this page, how to do it? Like whenever this messgage is shown it should just swallow it and redirect to an existing route.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is the default "not found" error handler. You can define your own error handler by creating a UI component (e.g. `VerticalLayout`) subclass that implements `HasErrorParameter<NotFoundException>`. Flow will automatically that class from the application in the same way that it picks up `@Route` annotated classes.

Comment: Hey thanks, I did try it like this, but it does not seem to work. @ Component
public class NoRouteErrorHandler implements HasErrorParameter<NotFoundException> {

 @Override
 public int setErrorParameter(BeforeEnterEvent event, ErrorParameter<NotFoundException> parameter) {
  System.out.println("setErrorParameter");
  event.forwardTo(View.class);
  return 80;
 }

Comment: Your example class isn't a Vaadin UI component. In addition to `implements HasErrorParameter<NotFoundException> `, it also needs e.g. `extends VerticalLayout`. I'll clarify the answer to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it this way:

```
@Tag(Tag.DIV)
@DefaultErrorHandler
public class MYNoRouteHandler extends RouteNotFoundError {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7169334501543395112L;
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyNoRouteHandler.class);

@Override
public int setErrorParameter(BeforeEnterEvent event, ErrorParameter<NotFoundException> parameter) {
    log.debug("Not existing view requested with name: /" + event.getLocation().getPath());
    log.debug("Redirect user to /start");
    event.forwardTo(StartView.class);
    return HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND;
    }
}
```

Thanks one more time for helping me out. Sometimes i wonder why others did not ask. Maybe they read the manual?